# mustacheコマンドの-vオプションでエラーメッセージが表示されてしまう

Tags: ruby

テンプレートエンジン[mustache](http://mustache.github.io)のコマンドを-vオプションを指定して実行すると以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示されます。原因を教えてください。
なお、-vオプションを指定した際にエラーが出る以外には、特に問題なくmustacheを使うことができています。

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ mustache -v
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mustache-1.0.0/bin/mustache:52:in `block (2 levels) in parse_options': uninitialized constant Mustache::Version (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/optparse.rb:1390:in `call'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/optparse.rb:1390:in `block in parse_in_order'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/optparse.rb:1346:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/optparse.rb:1346:in `parse_in_order'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/optparse.rb:1340:in `order!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/optparse.rb:1432:in `permute!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/optparse.rb:1454:in `parse!'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mustache-1.0.0/bin/mustache:64:in `parse_options'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mustache-1.0.0/bin/mustache:94:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/mustache:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/mustache:23:in `<main>'
```

【動作環境】
　Mustache: v1.0.0
　OS: CentOS 6.6
　Ruby: 2.1.2p95
　Gem: 2.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

バグです。

https://github.com/mustache/mustache/pull/189

VERSION と Version の typo です。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。バグでしたか。

Comment: マージされました。 https://github.com/mustache/mustache/pull/189

Comment: マージされた修正を個別に取り込んだら-vがエラーなく実行できるようになりました。ありがとうございます。